# column '_id' does not exist although ID have changed to _id

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have rename my `ID` to `_id`, but still get `column '_id' does not exist` ...Have I missed anything?

**MyDatabaseelper.java**

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="alm.db";
    public static final String TABLE_INFO="Information";
    public static final String TABLE_WORKFORCE="WorkForce";
    public static final  String TABLE_WORKDETAILS="WorkDetails";
    public static final String Subcontractors="Subcontractors";
    public static final String NumberOfPerson="NumberOfPerson";
    public static final String NumberOfHours="NumberOfHours";
    public static final String ID="_id";
    public static final String TimeIn_Info="timeIn_Info";
    public static final String TimeOut_Info="timeOut_Info";

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKFORCE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,Subcontractors TEXT,NumberOfPerson INTEGER,NumberOfHours TEXT, TInfo_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TInfo_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(ID))");

}
```

**ListDisplay.java**

```
public class ListDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
    InfoAPI sqlcon;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listdisplay1);
        sqlcon = new InfoAPI(this);
        final String name1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        BuildList(name1);
    }

    public void BuildList(String name) {
        final String name1 = name;
        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor cursor=sqlcon.readEntry(name1);

       String[] columns=new String[]{
               MyDatabaseHelper.Weather,MyDatabaseHelper.Date,MyDatabaseHelper.Status,MyDatabaseHelper.TimeIn,MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut
       };

        int[] to=new int[]{
                R.id.weather,R.id.date,R.id.status,R.id.in,R.id.out
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.listdispaly,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);






    }

}
```

**InfoAPI.java**

```
  public Cursor readEntry(String name)
    {
        Cursor c=database.rawQuery("SELECT  Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " WHERE Name = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(name)}, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

**LogCat Error**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:180)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:157)
            at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:96)
            at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
            at com.example.project.project.ListDisplay.BuildList(ListDisplay.java:49)
            at com.example.project.project.ListDisplay.onCreate(ListDisplay.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you create table queries are still using "ID" (hard-coded string)

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME)");
   db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKFORCE + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,Subcontractors TEXT,NumberOfPerson INTEGER,NumberOfHours TEXT, TInfo_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TInfo_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(ID))");
}
```

you will have to force an upgrade of your db either uninstalling completly the app from your device and reinstalling it again or incrementing VERSION.

The `SimpleCursorAdapter` wants the `_id` in the cursor. Add it to the query, E.g.

```
 Cursor c=database.rawQuery("SELECT _id,  Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " WHERE Name = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(name)}, null);
```

Comment: I have created a new db but it still the same

Comment: did you change the query to have `_id` in its selection ?

Comment: and you have the same stacktrace as the one you posted in the question?

Comment: after added comma after SELECT_id, now I get  column 'weather' does not exist

Comment: can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371558/how-to-retrieve-data-based-on-two-conditions-given)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Uninstall the App to reinstall after making the ID to _id change. Also you can Override the OnUpgrade method which is helper method under SQLiteOpenHelper class, to upgrade your database by giving a different version Number to the database, which then deletes the older database version. This ensures you do not have to reinstall your app every time when there is a change in database.

you can use the following code sinnipet.

```
@Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS donotes");
            //Create the data base with the New Data
            onCreate(db);
        }
```

Use like this:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME);");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKFORCE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  ,Subcontractors TEXT,NumberOfPerson INTEGER,NumberOfHours TEXT, TInfo_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(TInfo_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(ID));");

}
```

Comment: I edited  my post. use the Update code snippet. Semicolon at the end of the create call need to be placed.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help.

Comment: After creating the data-base, the _id should also be fetched by the Loader, else the exception repeats.