# How to retrieve data based on two conditions given?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, where-clause

In MainActivity, I want the `listView` display the data with a specific month.

```
 public void BuildList()
    {
        sqlcon.open(); // object of InfoAPI
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),month+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor cursor1=sqlcon.readData(month);
        String[] columns=new String[]{
        MyDatabaseHelper.Date,MyDatabaseHelper.TimeIn_Info,MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut_Info
        };

        int[] to=new int[]
         {
           R.id.date,R.id.timeIn,R.id.timeOut
         };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.retrieve_data,
                cursor1,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder());
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

}
```

**InfoAPI**

```
public Cursor readData(int m)
    {
        Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT _id, Date,Weather,Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + 
                " WHERE Name = ? and strftime('%m',Date)= ?", 
                new String[]{"LCV"}, new String[]{String.valueOf(m)},null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

**Error**

```
 Error:(54, 26) error: no suitable method found for rawQuery(String,String[],String[],<null>)
    method SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String,String[]) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String,String[],CancellationSignal) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Error:(106, 30) error: method readData in class InfoAPI cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I get a little bit confused in rawQuery. What is the correct way to write in order to retrieve the data based on two conditions ?

**Edited**

```
 public Cursor readData(int m)
    {
        Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT _id, Date,Weather,Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO +
                        " WHERE Name = ? and strftime('%m',Date)= ?",
                new String[]{ "LCV", String.valueOf(m) }, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

For the Date column, it holds the date format `19-12-2015`. No error now but no data display on ListView.

Comment: Are there any errors? I think you need to put your parameters to the query in a single String[]

Comment: Yeah, see, "no suitable method found". What does that mean to you?

Comment: @cricket_007 is it because of `strftime` ?

Comment: No, look at the [documentation for rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). How many parameters are there? What types are they? How does that differ from what you have?

Comment: @cricket_007 I still didn't get it..

Comment: I was trying to help you learn to read the documentation. Your error is clear - you aren't calling the method correctly. So, the first place you should look is the Android documentation for the proper way to call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rawQuery method that takes two separate `String[]`. As pointed out by the error

```
no suitable method found for rawQuery(String,String[],String[],<null>)
```

Instead of querying like so

```
rawQuery(query, new String[]{"LCV"}, new String[]{String.valueOf(m)},null);
```

Use this instead, where your columns for the WHERE statement are in the same `String[]`

```
rawQuery(query, new String[]{ "LCV", String.valueOf(m) }, null);
```

Or even simply this because you don't need the null at the end

```
rawQuery(query, new String[]{ "LCV", String.valueOf(m) });
```

And since you are querying on a date format with zero padded numbers, use `String.format("%02d",m)` instead of `String.valueOf(m)`.

Comment: thanks for your help bro..but I don't know why no data are displayed on the listView

Comment: Welcome. I won't be able to help with that because there are too many pieces to check. Such as...  Are you sure data exists for the month you are querying? Are you sure your query is correct and actually returning results? Are you sure you are using the SimpleCursorAdapter correctly?

Comment: Before I add the `month` parameter, which I only use name(LCV), the data get displayed

Comment: strftime with a %m is a zero padded month. If you are searching for a month less than 10, then it will return zero results because the String.valueOf(m) will be a single digit.

Comment: I have put +1 in  this line `int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;`. Do I need to add +1 in `%m` ?

Comment: What is the value of month? Should be 12 if you are getting the current month. Is there data in the table with a name of LCV and a date with the month 12? And you can't just add 1 to the %m. You'd have to use `String.format("%02d", m)` instead of `String.valueOf(m)`.

Comment: 2 digits with zero padding on the left. `String.format("%02d", 8)` returns "08". String.valueOf(8) returns "8". If you query where Date = 8, it wouldnt work because it expects "08" instead. `String.format("%02d", 10)` returns "10"

Comment: I use `new String[]{ "LCV", String.format("%02d", 12)}, null);`, the data still cannot be displayed...

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you other than to verify there actually is a row with LCV as the name and a date with the corresponding month. If you still cant figure it out, you should post a new question since you've already accepted an answer here.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373159/data-cannot-be-retrieved-by-given-a-specific-month