# Data cannot be retrieved by given a specific month

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, monthcalendar

I wanted to retrieve data which month is belong to 12.

```
 public Cursor readData()
    {
        Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT _id, Date,Weather,Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO +
                        " WHERE  strftime('%m',Date) = ? ",
                new String[]{12+""}, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

However, no data get displayed. I have make sure it has a data with a month 12.

**MyDatabaseHelper for Table_Info**

```
     public static final String TABLE_INFO="Information";
     public static final String Date="Date";
     public static final String Status="Status";
     public static final String TimeIn_Info="TimeIn_Info";
     public static final String TimeOut_Info="TimeOut_Info";
     public static final String Weather="Weather";
     public static final String Name="Name";

     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME)");
      }
```

I select the date by using `date-time picker` and the Date holds the date with the format `19-12-2015`.

> There are nothing wrong with my database because data get displayed
>   when I change the condition to name.

Can someone helps me to figure out the problem ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the db file if possible

Comment: My best guess would be because of the column name date since its also a keyword you might wanna change it and execute

Comment: @ZaidHoona did you want to see a screen shot of the db file?

Comment: Actually want the ddl thats all, i.e. the creation statement and the data you are filling some example thats all

Comment: @ZaidHoona please check

Comment: I am having some problem in loging images from i.stack.imgur i cant even see the tag image of android on stack overflow

Comment: Is that your exact code statement above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98431/discussion-between-john-and-zaid-hoona).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to change insert datetime to format: 2015-12-15 (%Y-%m-%d)

Comment: i have try with 12 not result and '12' have result

Comment: Sure. Do you mind telling me what format your Date string is? Is it YYYY-MM-DD, by chance?

Comment: @GiapLee thanks for your answer. I used your code, but the data get displayed even it is january

Comment: hi. you can try with new resolve option i just added because i think strftime('%m', '15-12-2015') -> return wrong position of month number in date string